# accessing websphere dmgr issue

Tags: websphere

whem attemping to open administrative web console i got this response:

This page isn’t working right now [dmgr host] didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

When attempting to retrieve the server status for the dmgr server using the WebSphere Application Server administrative client, the following error message is displayed:

`ADMU0500I: Retrieving server status for dmgr ADMU0002E: Exception attempting to process server dmgr: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.RetryCandidateException: java.io.IOException: SSL connection was closed by peer`

i am trying to get the root cause of the probles but the only file that is logging in the dmgr server is startServer.log and serverStatus.log the rest doesn't log any thing.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: yes, I was trying to stop and start DMGR from ./startManager and ./stopManager, but it was not responding. so I just killed the process from the task manager and started dmgr again, and it worked. but I don't know why this behavior.